# Read image from stream database

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Dear's all, I have an issue in streaming database.
I have already write an image there and now i want to recall and put it in a PictureBox.
Is there anyone how can tell me the best practice to do it?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't keep images on `FileSystem` and keep metadata in dbase ? working with `FileSystem` is more easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way IMO is to read all the data from the database and write it into a `MemoryStream`. Rewind the stream (set `Position=0`) and then use [`new Bitmap(stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) or [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx). Note that you should *not* dispose of the stream... the bitmap effectively "owns" the stream after you've constructed it.

Comment: thank you that was my first idea but I'm seeking to find anything better than that (if there is any).

Comment: @Lefteris: What sort of "better" are you looking for? What don't you like about that solution?

Comment: It is not what i don't like but IF there is something else than that. And as far as I see that is the best practice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

1. Cal the `ExecuteNonQuery` method to get a byte array with the image
2. Create a new `MemoryStream` around the byte array (do not destroy the stream as the Image object will continue to use it)
3. Call `Image.FromStream` to read the stream
4. Set this image to the `Image` property of a PictureBox.

Answer (score 2):

When the image is small or the traffic is insignificant, any of the methods mentioned above works and they make great demoware. Things start to get out of hand as the size of the image increases, because all these solutions require the entire image to be stored as a byte array in memory. If the load on the server is significant, having all these copies  of image files taking up valuable process address space real estate adds up and can dramatically impact performance.

It *is* possible to read from a database with stream semantics, so that no entire copy of the file is ever stored in memory:

- use the [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) hint:

> Provides a way for the DataReader to
>   handle rows that contain columns with
>   large binary values. Rather than
>   loading the entire row,
>   SequentialAccess enables the
>   DataReader to load data as a stream.
>   You can then use the GetBytes or
>   GetChars method to specify a byte
>   location to start the read operation,
>   and a limited buffer size for the data
>   being returned.

- read the data in chunks, using [`SqlDataReader.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx)
- write the data to the output stream in chunks

The last point is a little problematic. You can either write the stream into a WWW server local folder that is virtually mapped to the site and then return an URL to this file. Or you can have an URL that reads the picture itself and writes the image straight to the ASP output cache. The first method can pay off for frequently accessed images, as the cached file can server multiple requests but it requires invalidation and cleanup logic. The second method is better for unfrequented accessed images, but requires proper routing logic in your app.

When things start getting really hot then the issue of threads being blocked in marshaling these images start showing up and you will have to move to [Asynchronous pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx), a model that fits stream copy semantics perfectly.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu. I try to use your solution but i'm facing some issues. It is obviouse that some where I have wrong. So please assist me on this:

Comment: Dim readSQLcomm As SqlCommand. Dim imgReader As SqlDataReader. Dim imgBuffer() As Byte. Dim imgStream As FileStream.

Comment: readSQLcomm = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & tName & "_Image WHERE " & tName & "Parent_ID = '" & imgID & "'", SQLConn)

Comment: imgReader = readSQLcomm.ExecuteReader(Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu. From this point and on everything goes wrong Please can you assist me?

Comment: Before you access column 0 you must first open the reader with `imgReader.Read()`

Comment: What i've done is this: While imgReader.Read(). imgObj = imgReader(0). imgReader.GetBytes(0, 0, imgBuffer, 0, imgObj.Length). End While